# Qt programm can't open my MySql database

Tags: c++, mysql, database, eclipse, qt

When i push the Button, it views this error : QSqlQuery::exec: database not open

```
void Tester::pushButtonClicked()
{
    if (database.open() )
    {
        model->setQuery("SELECT id, Nachname, Vorname, Ort FROM testtable");
        model->setHeaderData(0, Qt::Horizontal, tr("ID"));
        model->setHeaderData(1, Qt::Horizontal, tr("Nachnamme"));
        model->setHeaderData(2, Qt::Horizontal, tr("Vorname"));
        model->setHeaderData(3, Qt::Horizontal, tr("Ort"));
    } else
    {
        qDebug("Nicht geöffnet");
    }
    meineView->setModel(model);
}
```

whats wrong ? database is a QSqlDatabase . model is a QSqlQueryModel.
I have connect it so :

```
database = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL", "conn1");
//database->addDatabase("QMYSQL", "conn1");
database.setHostName("127.0.0.1");
database.setPort(3306);
database.setDatabaseName( "mydb" );
database.setUserName("root");
database.setPassword("XXXX");
if ( !database.open() )
{
    qDebug("Couldn't open DB");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the answer !
I have forget to set the database fot the Query. 
It must look like : `model->setQuery("SELECT id, Nachname, Vorname, Ort FROM testtable", database);`

Comment: You can (should) also accept your own answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

What is the error you are facing ? Use QSqlDatabase::lastError() to retrieve the error, if any, on opening the connection.

Also I think you are trying to open the database twice. Once when you create the database object and other in the button click. Check that database is already open using the isOpen() method on button click.

Comment: i cant use QSqlDatabase::lastError() , it says "Invalid arguments '
Candidates are:
QSqlError lastError()" But "QSqlError lastError()" dont works .

Comment: When i write it so, it makes the same error , i delete the .isOpen in my init method: 
`if(database.isOpen()== false)
 {  database.open();
   model->setQuery("SELECT id, Nachname, Vorname, Ort FROM testtable");
   model->setHeaderData(0, Qt::Horizontal, tr("ID"));
   model->setHeaderData(1, Qt::Horizontal, tr("Nachnamme"));
   model->setHeaderData(2, Qt::Horizontal, tr("Vorname"));
   model->setHeaderData(3, Qt::Horizontal, tr("Ort"));

 }`